# Implication of Inequalities with Sum and Difference being Greater / Lesser than Constant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

Please, let me know if the below is too trivial and I can delete this question.

We are given that

$$ x+y \geq c$$

$$ x-y \leq c$$

$$  x, c \geq 0$$

Can we conclude that $y\geq0$?

Please also, let me know of any other results we can conclude from the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course! Because $$x+y-(x-y)\geq c-c=0,$$
for which we not need $x\geq0$, $c\geq0$.